# How can I properly trigger the redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to get data from json-server with Redux and I am trying to send it to the component. But at some point there are things that I cannot understand.

There is no problem when I apply the same redux logic for the other data segments, but when I apply it for the leaders section, there is a problem. Functions like fetchComments, fetchPromos, fetchDishes are working. But when I add the fetchLeaders function, the redux store does not trigger the necessary

This is my ActionCreator file.

ActionCreator.js

```
.....
.....
export function fetchLeaders() {
    return async function (dispatch) {
        const returnData = await axios.get(baseUrl + 'leaders')
        dispatch(addLeaders(returnData.data))
    }
}

export const addLeaders = (leaders) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_LEADERS,
    payload: leaders
})
.....
.....
```

leaders.js

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes'

export const Leaders = (state={
                                leaders: []
                                },action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.ADD_LEADERS:
            return{
                ...state,
                leaders:action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

MainComponent.js

```
.....
.....
import { fetchDishes, fetchComments, fetchPromos, postComment, fetchLeaders } from '../redux/ActionCreators';
.
.
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        DISHES: state.dishes,
        COMMENTS: state.comments,
        PROMOTIONS: state.promotions,
        LEADERS:state.leaders
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    
    addComment: function(dishId, rating, author, comment) {
        console.log("Çağırıldı.")
        return dispatch(postComment(dishId, rating, author, comment))
    },
    fetchDishes: () => {dispatch(fetchDishes())},
    

    resetFeedbackForm: () => { dispatch(actions.reset('feedback'))},
    fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
    fetchPromos: () => dispatch(fetchPromos()),
    fetchLeaders: () => dispatch(fetchLeaders())
})

.
.
class  Main extends Component {
  
  constructor(props){
      super(props)

  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchLeaders();
    this.props.fetchDishes();
    this.props.fetchComments();
    this.props.fetchPromos();

  }

  render(){
      return (
            <div>
               .
               .
                            <Home dish={this.props.DISHES.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.featured)[0]}
                                dishesLoading={this.props.DISHES.isLoading}
                                dishesErrMess={this.props.DISHES.errMess}
                                promotion={this.props.PROMOTIONS.promotions.filter((promo) => promo.featured)[0]}
                                promoLoading={this.props.PROMOTIONS.isLoading}
                                promoErrMess={this.props.PROMOTIONS.errMess}
                                leader={this.props.LEADERS.leaders.filter((leader) => leader.featured)[0]}
                                />
                        .
                        .
            </div>
    
  )}
}
.....
.....
```

Comment: I don't know my typo, but dispatch (addLeaders (returnData.data) is missing a parenthesis here.

Comment: What does "there is a problem." mean?

Comment: @AndyRay Functions like fetchComments, fetchPromos, fetchDishes are working. But when I add the fetchLeaders function, the redux store does not trigger the necessary.

Comment: What does "trigger the necessary." mean? Please be specific about what you are expecting to happen and what isn't happening. Make sure you debug your own code first to understand where it's not working. For example, is `dispatch(addLeaders(returnData.data))` running? What is `returnData.data` ?